# How to concatenate 600 csv files into one using only files with more than 2KB

Tags: python, csv

I have managed to concatenate all 600 csv files into one, however I only want files with more than 2KB as they have no data in.

Is there a way to add to this code to do that?

The code I used to create the single csv file is:

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv

indir = Path(r'C:\\Users\gerardchurch\Documents\Data\dev_en')
outfile = Path(r"C:\\Users\gerardchurch\Documents\Data\output.csv")


def find_header_from_all_files(indir):
    columns = set()
    print("Looking for column names in", indir)
    for f in indir.glob('*.csv'):
        with f.open() as sample_csv:
            sample_reader = csv.DictReader(sample_csv)
            try:
                first_row = next(sample_reader)
            except StopIteration:
                print("File {} doesn't contain any data. Double check 
this".format(f))
                continue
            else:
                columns.update(first_row.keys())
    return columns


columns = find_header_from_all_files(indir)
print("The columns are:", sorted(columns))

with outfile.open('w') as outf:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=list(columns))
    wr.writeheader()
    for inpath in indir.glob('*.csv'):
        print("Parsing", inpath)
        with inpath.open() as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            wr.writerows(reader)
print("Done, find the output at", outfile)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try `import pandas`

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

use the `os` module. you can create a check like so

```
if os.stat(fname).st_size > dsize:
   func(fname)
```

where `fname` is your file path `dsize` is the lower threshold of your file size and `func(fname)` is what you want to do with that file when it passes the check

the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html) are pretty straight forward